# Collection or Template in Terraform HCL

Tags: terraform, hcl

I'm trying to find directions on how to do a pretty simple thing in HCL.  I have one block like this

```tf
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "qa" {
    name "qa1"
    #insert settings here        
}
```

And I want to insert a collection of settings where that comment is.  But the config is not an array it should be something like

```tf
desired_block "settings" {
    setting {}
    setting {}
}
```

How would I inject something like desired block?

Comment: Unfortunately, HCL can't do that. You'd have to write some sort of wrapper that has the smarts to put the `*.tf` HCL together.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating multiple blocks you can put an array of settings and It would work. Like

```tf
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "qa" {
    name = "qa1"
    settings = ["${var.settings_array}"]
}
```

Here `var.settings_array` is an array of settings, like `[<settings1>, <settings2>, ...]`.